# Reference doc to know the reason for making any rule in java

Tags: java, language-design

When something new is introduced Java, Oracle releases API doc and tutorials about how to use it and rules to follow. But does it release any document about the decisions or thoughts behind making the API that way or why the design is made like that.

For example,

1. Why we don't have static and protected outer classes.
2. Why we can't extend more than one class in Java.
3. Why Subclass overridden method cannot throw more exceptions than that of superclass method.

These might be obvious for someone who is working on Java for a long time and came to know about the valid reason behind these through experience.
But someone who is new to Java or someone who is using it for first time might not get it straightway.
So is there any reference doc released by Oracle which can be referred to know the reasons behind those rules.

Comment: No, but if you follow the mailing lists and bug repositories for any and all [JSRs](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/all), you'll get a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not for already existing rules but yes for newly added features in the particular release.
When ever java releases the new version, it is releasing the release not for that version regarding what all enhancements and features are added with the example.

Following is the link of Java 7 Release Note with all added features and enhancements -
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html

On this page if you click on any feature, it will take to the detail of particular feature.
for example, on this page if you click on - **Multithreaded Custom Class Loaders in Java SE 7** it will take to the page which contains the detail like what was the scenario where it was required and what is now supported to come out of it as -
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/cl-mt.html

Answer (score 0):

Well as others answered, there is no such documentation but you can easily find the answers on the net (on Java release notes, JSRs,  forums...and this site.

Concerning your precise questions:

1. `protected` and `static` are by nature used in the scope of a class.
2. Inheritance is limited to one class because of the [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) .`interface` are Java's (and others such as c#) solution for that.
3. You cannot make incompatible changes on the methods through overriding. Adding one exception breaks the possibility of polymorphism. In that case, the code calling this method should know the exact implementation to correctly handle the exception.